# Justify "orphans" to the right margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

I'm typesetting a book with some song lyrics, but at some points, the verses have too many words to fit on the page -- so they overflow and spill over to the next line. To make this read better I want to justify these orphans to the right.

So the question goes: **How do I make the overflowing words and only the overflowing words justify to the right?**

Here is a MWE that is essentially the same as my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Verse one is really nice

So is verse two

Verse three is a whole lot longer than both

Verse four is shorter

\vspace{\fill}\pagebreak

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

And a picture showing the MWE. The 'than both' is supposed to justify right.

[image]

[Right justify inline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22745/right-justify-inline) seems like it could be adapted to work.

Comment: Can you make an example of a lyric you're typesetting? The answer mostly depends on how you do it.

Comment: @egreg I've made a new MWE that better shows how I'm working with the lyrics. I'm not sure that I can actually use the original lyrics, but at least the layout is more true to document I'm working with

Comment: Have you looked into the `verse` package?

Comment: I'm looking into it! It seems like it might do, but! I'd still like to see an answer to this question :)

Comment: A point of information: what you're referring to is not technically an "orphan". An orphan is a line of text that spills onto the next page or column, whereas you have a paragraph that spills onto the next line.

Comment: @JohnWickerson Totally true, I guess the reason I used 'orphan' was because I mostly dealt with singular words spilling into the next line.

Comment: @JohnWickerson You're right that the example is technically not an orphan, but you are confusing _ophans_ and _widows_ in your definition. An orphan is a very short line that "is left behind", i.e. it ends up a paragraph (or opens up one alone at the end of a page), creating a mostly white line, while a widow is what you are defining.(see [Widows and orphans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widows_and_orphans) on wikipedia).

Comment: Ah yes. In which case, depending on which reference you consult, Henrik's usage may well be correct.

Comment: @JohnWickerson According to this Wikipedia page, there doesn't seems to be a clear consensus on the definitions of *orphan* and *widow*...

Answer (score 2):

Following egreg's suggestion to use the [`verse`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/verse) package...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{verse}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
Verse one is really nice

So is verse two

Verse three is a whole lot longer than both

Verse four is shorter
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on a solution in [justify inline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22745/right-justify-inline?lq=1) I've found that this works too. (Requires manual work)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
begin{multicols}{2}
Verse one is really nice

So is verse two

Verse three is a whole lot longer \hspace*{\fill}than both

Verse four is shorter

\vspace{\fill}\pagebreak

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```